# Finding branch of a multivalued function given two branch cuts.

Tags: complex-analysis

I am having trouble understanding how to determine something. I have the function $h(z) = \sqrt{z^2+1}$. I need to choose the branch cut as a segment that goes from $z = i$ to $z = -i$ and such that the resulting branch of the function, $H(z)$, makes $H(1)>0$. I don't know how to proceed. I had thought about doing this:

$$h(z) = \sqrt{(z+i)(z-i)}$$

And, by making $z=r\text{e}^{i\theta + 2\pi k i}$ and $i = \text{e}^{\frac{i\pi}{2}+ 2\pi k i}$ one can re-express the function as:
$$h(z) = e^{\pi k i} \sqrt{(r\text{e}^{i\theta} + e^{i\pi / 2})(r\text{e}^{i\theta} - e^{i\pi / 2})}$$

Where choosing different values of $k$ ($k\in \mathbb{Z}$) would mean (I think) going to different branches of the function. My problem is, I don't know how to relate this to to specific branch cut the problem is telling me. How should I proceed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it simpler to define the square root in the plane with some ray from the origin to infinity removed, therefore I would proceed as follows.

Let $D$ denote the complex plane with the segment from $-i$ to $i$ removed. The Möbius transformation $T(z) = (z-i)/(z+i)$ maps $D$ onto $G = \Bbb C \setminus (-\infty, 0]$, with $T(1) = -i$. On $G$ we can define $S$ as the principal branch of the square root.

Then $H(z) = (z+i)S(T(z))$ satisfies
$$
 H(z)^2 = (z+i)^2 \frac{z-i}{z+i} = z^2+1
$$
so that $H$ is a holomorphic square root of $z^2+1$ in $D$. Also
$$
 H(1) = (1+i) S(-i) = (1+i)\frac{1-i}{\sqrt 2} = \sqrt 2 > 0 \, .
$$

Comment: I understand what you did, but not why. Why think of a Mobius transformation right now? I am not questioning your approach, of course, I just want to know how you came up with that because I don't think I would've been able to find that solution.

Comment: @coffee_pls: The idea is to map the segment $[-i, i]$ to the negative real axis, so that you can use the principal branch of the square root in the complement.

Comment: Okay, just to make sure I understand. When we work with the function $f(z) = \sqrt{z}$, we know there's a branch in the negative real axis. So what you're trying to do is find a transformation that takes any value in D and takes it to the complex plane minus the real negative axis, so that we can use the principal branch of the square root, right?

Comment: @coffee_pls: Well, the branch cut need not be the negative real axis, you can choose any ray (or in fact any simple curve) from $0$ to $\infty$, because there is a holomorphic square root on any simply-connected domain not containing the origin. – I chose this construction because it is simple. I do not claim that this is only way to proceed.

Comment: Okay, I understand now. I just wanted to make sure that I get why you did what you did. Thanks for you help!

Comment: How did you come up with the adequate Mobius transformation? I have been reading about cross products and how to determine the unique transformation that takes three points to three other points in the Riemann sphere but I am not sure about how to proceed.

Comment: @coffee_pls: Another important property of Möbius transformations is that circles or lines are mapped to circles or lines. If $T(i) = 0$ and $T(-i) = \infty$ then the segment from $i$ to $-i$ is mapped to some ray from $0$ to $\infty$. And since $T(1) = -1$, this ray is the negative real axis.